# Create ggplot2 density plot from binned data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to visualize a distribution using ggplot2 tools like density plots and ECDFs. The challenge is that I only have binned data available and not the individual samples. That is, each row in my data frame has columns `bin,count` rather than individual samples. However, the bins can be quite narrow e.g. with data spread over 500 bins.

Are there some reasonable solutions? My first thought was to somehow expand each bin into individual samples by repeating the upper bound of the bin `count` times. I am not sure the best way to do that nor whether it is especially inadvisable.

Tips welcome!

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be very helpful here.

Comment: Sure, since you already havepre-calculated bins, use `geom_bar` or `geom_histogram(..., stat = "identity")`.

Comment: Roman is correct. Depending on how your bins are named, you may have to turn them into an ordered factor first to make sure they appear in the right order.

Comment: If the bins really are narrow, won't a column plot or line plot of the counts approximate a density plot? What's the problem with that approach for your case? In general, I think it would be a bad idea to manufacture a "fake" sample to plot if you've got "real" data that can give you just as much information.

Comment: If the bins are truly narrow it won't matter too much, you just lose some resolution. If you have `df <- data.frame(bin = 1:5, count = c(3, 5, 7, 15, 2))` you could use `df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(df$bin, df$count))`